# UBSan: boost::program_options with std::string

Tags: c++, boost, clang++, boost-program-options, ubsan

We are currently investigating a possible undefined behaviour in our program  that is flagged by clang7 UBSan in combination with boost::program_option from boost 1.69.0. We have created the following working example that can we compiled and run with `clang++ -std=c++17 -fsanitize=undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer -lboost_program_options debug.cpp  && UBSAN_OPTIONS=print_stacktrace=1 ./a.out`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main() {
    std::string test_string = "";
    po::options_description desc("test");
    desc.add_options()
        ("string", po::value<std::string>(&test_string))
    ;

    constexpr char *argv[] = {"test", "--string", "test"};
    constexpr int argc = sizeof(argv) / sizeof(char*);

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    std::cerr << "Before notify" << std::endl;
    po::notify(vm);

    std::cout << "string -> " << test_string << std::endl;
}
```

We get the following output:

```
/usr/include/boost/any.hpp:249:17: runtime error: downcast of address 0x5638e42892e0 which does not point to an object of type 'any::holder<typename remove_cv<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >::type>' (aka 'holder<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >')
0x5638e42892e0: note: object is of type 'boost::any::holder<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >'
 00 00 00 00  00 55 f9 63 28 7f 00 00  f8 92 28 e4 38 56 00 00  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  74 65 73 74
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              vptr for 'boost::any::holder<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >'
    #0 0x5638e1b06d6e in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >* boost::any_cast<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(boost::any*) (/home/gereon/carl/src/tests/carl-settings/a.out+0x4cd6e)
    #1 0x5638e1b0672c in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const* boost::any_cast<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(boost::any const*) (/home/gereon/carl/src/tests/carl-settings/a.out+0x4c72c)
    #2 0x5638e1b03625 in boost::program_options::typed_value<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char>::notify(boost::any const&) const (/home/gereon/carl/src/tests/carl-settings/a.out+0x49625)
    #3 0x7f2863f6a71e in boost::program_options::variables_map::notify() (/usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.69.0+0x5771e)
    #4 0x5638e1afa2ae in main (/home/gereon/carl/src/tests/carl-settings/a.out+0x402ae)
    #5 0x7f2863a13222 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x24222)
    #6 0x5638e1ad33ad in _start (/home/gereon/carl/src/tests/carl-settings/a.out+0x193ad)

/usr/include/boost/any.hpp:249:114: runtime error: member access within address 0x5638e42892e0 which does not point to an object of type 'any::holder<typename remove_cv<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >::type>' (aka 'holder<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >')
0x5638e42892e0: note: object is of type 'boost::any::holder<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >'
 00 00 00 00  00 55 f9 63 28 7f 00 00  f8 92 28 e4 38 56 00 00  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  74 65 73 74
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              vptr for 'boost::any::holder<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >'
    #0 0x5638e1b06e36 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >* boost::any_cast<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(boost::any*) (/home/gereon/carl/src/tests/carl-settings/a.out+0x4ce36)
    #1 0x5638e1b0672c in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const* boost::any_cast<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(boost::any const*) (/home/gereon/carl/src/tests/carl-settings/a.out+0x4c72c)
    #2 0x5638e1b03625 in boost::program_options::typed_value<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char>::notify(boost::any const&) const (/home/gereon/carl/src/tests/carl-settings/a.out+0x49625)
    #3 0x7f2863f6a71e in boost::program_options::variables_map::notify() (/usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.69.0+0x5771e)
    #4 0x5638e1afa2ae in main (/home/gereon/carl/src/tests/carl-settings/a.out+0x402ae)
    #5 0x7f2863a13222 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x24222)
    #6 0x5638e1ad33ad in _start (/home/gereon/carl/src/tests/carl-settings/a.out+0x193ad)

string -> test
```

As we can see it runs fine (`test_string` has the correct value afterwards). We have investigated into boost::program_options and boost::any and found the following:
In `program_options::typed_value::notify()` (#2) we get a boost::any and cast it to the type it is supposed to be by calling boost::any_cast().

Considering clang's output (`downcast of address 0x5638e42892e0 which does not point to an object of type 'any::holder<typename remove_cv<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >::type>' (aka 'holder<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >')` and `object is of type 'boost::any::holder<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >'`) we can only conclude that this boost::any instance in fact holds the correct member... in which case the downcast should be legal.

UBSan however states that no false positives are to be expected.

Interestingly we are not able to reproduce this error without program_options in the mix:

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void any_cast(const boost::any& a) {
    const std::string* t2 = boost::any_cast<std::string>(&a);
    std::cout << *t2 << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    boost::any a;
    a = std::string("test");
    any_cast(a);
}
```

Hence we suspect that (the precompiled) program_options may somehow mess with the std::string type.

By the way, valgrind does not report any errors for both programs.

Any ideas?

We have tried this on Arch linux (with boost 1.69.0-1, clang 7.0.1-1 using libstd++) and CentOS 7.6 (clang 7.0.0 using libc++ and boost 1.69.0 build with the same clang).

Comment: This seems to be related to the changes in boost regarding visibility. Git bisect traced this change to commit 16f52cede5bb0665f36c13dfd76c6badd719f21b, which activated ``-fvisibility-inlines-hidden`` and ``-fvisibility=hidden``

Comment: Maybe this is relevant?

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/program_options/issues/44

Comment: @user14717 The errors shown there are different ("load of value" instead of "downcast of"...). Also they all seem to show during parsing while ours only triggers on notify.

Comment: @ThE_-_BliZZarD Hm, interesting. So this may indeed be a false positive? (because the std::string from program_options is hidden and thus not matched against the std::string from the main binary or what is going on here?)